# If $\int_{1}^{\infty} |f(t)|^{2}\,dt < \infty$, is $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{|f(t)|}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt < \infty$?

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> If $\int_{1}^{\infty} |f(t)|^{2}\,dt < \infty$, is $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{|f(t)|}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt < \infty$?
>
> If Yes, give a proof. If no, give a counterexample.

I try to use Holder inequality to prove, but I couldn't prove and also I couldn't find counterexample.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: For ease of writing assume $f \geq 0$. What you would want to have happen is that $1/\sqrt{t}$ would be $L^2$ so you could use Cauchy-Schwarz, but it isn't, which suggests that $f$ should be "close" to $1/\sqrt{t}$ but decaying a little bit faster so that it is still $L^2$. Some tinkering with $x^{-p}$ for $p$ close to $1/2$  quickly fails. The usual trick is to then reach for logs to get something that decays just slightly faster, and this turns out to work as Clayton has showed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I didn't think of logs. Thanks!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with writing here, but thank you, Cameron Williams for editing and making others understand clearly!

Comment: I should rephrase a little bit: to prove the $\int f(t)/\sqrt{t} dt$ *converges* you would want to have $1/\sqrt{t}$ be $L^2$, but it isn't, which suggests that probably the integral doesn't have to converge if $f$ is just an arbitrary $L^2$ function. Generally to make integrals of products big you want to make the two factors close, so *for a counterexample* you want $f$ something in $L^2$ that is close to $1/\sqrt{t}$. You find that $t^{-p}$ doesn't help you, to make it $L^2$ you need $p>1/2$ which causes convergence. So you reach for logs to get just a little bit more decay and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\log(1+ t)}.$$ Then $$\int_1^\infty|f(t)|^2\,dt=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t\log^2(1+t)}<\infty$$ while we have on the other hand $$\int_1^\infty \frac{|f(t)|}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t\log(1+t)}\,dt=\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks!  It's the counterexample I was looking for!!!